# ng-style is not applying for the ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to apply random color to each name on repeated names. I don't get any error but colors are not applying.

```
<div ng-repeat= "item in items"  ng-style= "{'color': getcolor()}">
  {{item.name}}     
</div>
```

Here is the function:

```
 $scope.getcolor =  function(){
   var color = ["pink", "green", "blue"]
   var randoms = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
   return {"color" : randoms} 
}
```

Comment: getcolor should return a color name, not an object. Or you should use `ng-style="getcolor()"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div ng-repeat= "item in items"  ng-style= "getcolor()">
  {{item.name}}     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
return {"color": randoms};
```

should be changed to this:

```
return randoms:
```

to return the colour name.